# Which interpretation of quantum physics interprets superpositions in the sense of "an object *really* being in two places at once"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, superposition, quantum-states

In popular scientific literature one often reads of "objects being in two places at once" as a verbal way of explaining superposition of states (in the mathematical view of elements of a hilbert space). I haven't yet found out which interpretation of quantum mechanics does really view it this way.

I found out that there are realists and instrumentalists - the latter only looking at quantum states as useful mathematics (e.g. copenhagen), the former viewing quantum states as part of the reality (e.g. many world, spontaneous collapse,...) *(or viewing quantum states to have a "real" counterpart? seems like this is not quite the same?)*.

Now the former point of view still doesn't seem to equal "objects *really* being in two places at once" - because e.g. in many worlds, "real" isn't meant in a classical way, but rather in a way that needs two universes (so two classical worlds).

Is there a interpretation that interprets quantum superpositions that way, that there really (in a classical, physically meant common sense) are "objects in two places at once"?

Comment: Define "really". I think you're seeking a classical _and_, [as opposed to](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3) the non-classical concept of superposition. The point of interpretations of quantum mechanics is not to rewind to classical ideas, but to understand what quantum mechanics does differently.

Comment: @manuel459 The closest might be the many-worlds interpretation. In that scenario, if you believe that the universe 'really' splits after a measurement or interaction, then in a sense an object really 'is' in two different places at the same time. Of course this raises several more philosophical questions, like whether objects in two different 'universes' can be said to be the same. But that's not usually what people mean when they talk about 'objects being in two places at once' - it's more often a mischaracterisation of the linear combinations of two vectors from linear algebra 101.

Answer (score 1):

Probabilistic interpretation of quantum mechanics tells you that a physical quantity (observables, something that you can measure, otherwise it's hard to talk about Physics and reality, mathematically associated with Hermitian operators, $A$) may have several values when you measure it (associated with the eigenvalues, $s_i$ of the Hermitian operator), associated with the feasible states represented by eigenvectors $|\psi_i\rangle$ of the system.

Until you perform measurement, you really don't know the state of the system, you only could know the probability of the system to be in the different feasible states. Mathematically you can write the state function as a linear combination of the vector basis provided by the eigenvectors of the Hermitian operator of the physical quantities you're interested in.

$|\psi\rangle = \sum_i a_i |\psi_i\rangle$ (for operators with discrete spectrum)

Given the normalization condition

$1 = \langle\psi |\psi\rangle = \sum_i a_i^2$

the square $a_i^2$ of the coefficients $a_i$ of the expansion of the wave function on the eigenvectors (remember, associated with the feasible states), can be interpreted as the probability of finding the measurement $s_i$ of the physical quantity associated with the operator $A$, associated with state $|\psi_i\rangle$.

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: You can't think classically. You don't know the state of the system, but you only know the feasible states and their probability, until you measure it. Thus, "an object is not at two places at once", but you know that it can be in two places, you know the probabilities to find the object in each state, but you don't know where it is until you perform your measure. Once you perform a measure, you trust what you read as a result of your measurement

Comment: I understand. Although isn't it also part of interpretations to interpret what "is" beyond that - which might involve defining "reality" differently?

Comment: @basics Your model runs afoul of the results of entanglement experiments, where experiments don't simply reveal what classical state the system is in. A superposition is more profound than merely a probability that the system is in a given classical state.

Comment: @JohnDoty please, could you be more explicit?

Comment: @basics Study the Aspect experiment, which falsifies Bell's inequality, which would be true if your model worked.

Comment: @JohnDoty thanks, I'll do it, and then come back for further discussion. But now, I'm back to work. This evening, or next days

Answer (score 1):

The Transactional Interpretation of QM sort of treats particles as being in multiple places at once because it takes the wavefunction to be ontologically real. If the wavefunction is the particle, then the particle is distributed amongst different locations “during” transaction formation (a sort of quasi-time). On the other hand, it’s perhaps more natural to think of the particle as only existing at the emitter and absorber locations, and traveling directly between them only once the transaction has formed. After all, the completed transaction conveys a complete quantum of energy, momentum, spin, etc., which is how a particle is defined in QM. You can’t really have a partial particle, so is a distributed wavefunction really a distributed particle? I guess it’s a matter of semantics.

Answer (score 0):

When it is said that a single quantum particle can interfere with itself, or collapsing of a wavefunction. Defining a state by a vector or complex function in terms of basis vector is one thing and forbidding certain values of observable is another thing.

It is like you are seeing world as dice, where only integer numbers are allowed as outcome, and then do integration like continuous function because one don't know about system. But for do this, one need that matter behave as wave, which is not demonstrated yet.